# How to detect which country price is loading in InappPurchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I want to change my consumable subscription price. also i need to show the old price of the same consumable subscription. 
If i know which country i will compare with my local price list and i can display the old price.

OR

DO any one have different solution for my requirement?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to display a different price then what's on the SKProduct? It's usually better to create a new product if you want to change the price.

Answer (score 0):

```
((SKProduct *)product).priceLocale;
```

Comment: Albert Renshaw -- product).priceLocale gives us the format .  my question is which country price is loading(in display)

Comment: @SivaMurugan This returns the locale of the country in which the purchase is being made. Locales contains data about the country/region. For example you could do this: `[((SKProduct *)product).priceLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode]`